# Less - using classes created inside guarded mixins

Tags: css, less

I have the following less code:

```
.loop (@index) when (@index >= 10) {
  (~".font@{index}") {
    font-size: ~"@{index}px";
  }
  .loop(@index - 1);
} 
.loop (0) {}
.loop (10);
```

which output:

```
.font15 {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.font14 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.font13 {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.font12 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.font11 {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.font10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

In the end of the **Less** document I have this class:

```
.title{
    font-size:14px;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    .font13;
}
```

I'm using WinLess to compile it and I get an error saying the ".font13" is undefined
Is there any way to use a class defined "dynamically" in the same document?

Thanks!

Comment: In http://less2css.org this outputs to .font10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}.... how do you loop?

Comment: FYI-the problem is not that the class is created inside a guarded mixin, it is because of the dynamically generated class name. Martin's answer below is a good workaround for your situation.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately. The selector interpolation is just string interpolation, and the string gets then printed into CSS, so no class object is generated in the Less run.

So the best way to do something like this would be to design a **getter mixin** (that you can call from other rules) and maybe a generator mixin (that writes the `.font10`, `.font11`, ... `.fontNN` classes) ... the later is not necessary if you want to generate the classes only in the loop (and you can just merge it with the loop).

Something like this:

```
.getFont(@size) { font-size: ~"@{size}px"}

.genFontClass (@size) {
   (~".font@{size}") { .getFont(@size); }
}
```

and then you can use your loop to generate the `.fontNN` classes:

```
.loop (@index) when (@index >= 10) {
    .genFontClass (@index);
    .loop(@index - 1);
} 
.loop (@index) when (@index < 10) {}
```

using for example index 13:

```
.loop (13);
```

with output **CSS:**

```
.font13 {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.font12 {
  font-size: 12px;
}
.font11 {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.font10 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

and independently from this generated classes that got printed directly to the output CSS (and are inaccessible from other Less rules), you can call the getter mixin, to add desired properties to your rules, in our example the font for the desired index 13:

```
.title{
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    .getFont(13);
}
```

which will now add the font size property to the `.title` rule.

**CSS:**

```
.title {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great example of "less" thinking.  Great job.

Comment: @Slobaum even though you say I did *less* thinking, I will take it as a compliment ;-)